# Fibonacci sequence, proof verification.

Tags: proof-verification, induction, fibonacci-numbers

At the end of chapter $10$ of his "[*Book of Proof*](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/)", Hammack calls for a proof of the Fibonacci sequence in a form that I did not encounter before, I would like to know if the proof that I give for it is correct.

> - $30)$ Here $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number. Prove that
>     $$F_n=\frac{\left(\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2\right)^n-\left(\frac {1-\sqrt 5}2\right)^n}{\sqrt 5}\,.$$

First, I can see the golden ratio in the equation,
$$\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2 = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {F_{n+1}}{F_{n}} = \phi\,.$$

Then, I look at how $\frac {1-\sqrt 5}2$ relates to $\phi$,
$$\frac 1\phi = \frac 2{1+\sqrt 5} = \frac {2(1-\sqrt 5)}{1-5} = -\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\,.$$

Using this in the given formula for $F_n$ gives,

$$F_n = \frac 1{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi^n - \left(-\frac 1\phi\right)^n\right)\,.$$

So I will use that as a simplification for my induction proof.

I start by making sure that $F_n$ holds for $n=1$ and $n=2$ such that the inductive step can be taken,
$$F_1 = \frac 1{2 \sqrt 5}(1+\sqrt 5 -1 +\sqrt5) = \frac{2\sqrt 5}{2\sqrt5} = 1$$
$$F_2 = \frac 1{4 \sqrt 5}(1+2\sqrt 5+5 -1 +2\sqrt5 -5) = \frac{4\sqrt 5}{4\sqrt5} = 1$$
and I assume $F_{n} \,:\, n\in \Bbb Z^+$ is true.

We know that $F_n = F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ ergo,

$$\begin{align}
F_{n}+F_{n-1} & = \frac 1{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi^{n} - \left(-\frac 1\phi\right)^{n}\right) + \frac 1{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi^{n-1} - \left(-\frac 1\phi\right)^{n-1}\right)\\
 & = \frac 1{\sqrt 5}\left[\left(\phi^{n} + \phi^{n-1}\right) - \left(\left( -\frac 1\phi\right)^{n} + \left(-\frac 1\phi\right)^{n-1}\right)\right]\\
 & \require{cancel}\cancel{= \frac 1{\sqrt 5}\left[\phi^{n}(1 + \frac 1\phi) - \left(1 - \phi\right)\left( -\frac 1\phi\right)^{n}\right]} \\
\end{align}$$
$$\require{cancel}\cancel{1+\frac 1\phi = 1-\phi = \phi}$$
$$\require{cancel}\cancel{\therefore\quad F_{n}+F_{n-1} = \frac 1{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi^n - \left(-\frac 1\phi\right)^n\right) = F_{n+1}}$$

---

### Edit

Following the suggestions in the comments I edited the question and as suggested, I tried using the fact that $\phi$ and $-\frac{1}{\phi}$ are the roots of $x^2=x+1$ which I overlooked the first time.

So with that information in hand, I multiply $\phi^2 =\phi + 1$ by $\phi^{n-1}$ and $\left(-\frac 1\phi\right)^2 = \left(-\frac 1\phi\right) + 1$ by $\left(-\frac {1}\phi\right)^{n-1}$ as suggested to see,

$$\phi^{n+1} = \phi^n + \phi^{n-1}$$
$$\left(-\frac 1\phi\right)^{n+1} = \left(-\frac 1\phi\right)^n + \left(-\frac {1}\phi\right)^{n-1}$$

Then, knowing $F_1 =F_2 =1$ and assuming $F_{n} \,:\, n\in \Bbb Z^+$ is true, I use what I already found for $F_n+F_{n-1}$ and get,

$$\begin{align}
F_{n}+F_{n-1} & = \frac 1{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi^{n} - \left(-\frac 1\phi\right)^{n}\right) + \frac 1{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi^{n-1} - \left(-\frac 1\phi\right)^{n-1}\right) \\
& = \frac 1{\sqrt 5}\left[\left(\phi^{n} + \phi^{n-1}\right) - \left(\left( -\frac 1\phi\right)^{n} + \left(-\frac 1\phi\right)^{n-1}\right)\right]\\
& = \frac 1{\sqrt 5}\left[\phi^{n+1} - \left(-\frac 1{\phi}\right)^{n+1}\right] = F_{n+1} \\
\end{align}$$
$$\frac{F_{n}\implies F_{n+1}\;,\;F_{n}}{\therefore\;F_{n+1}}\qquad \text{modus ponens} \tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Is this proof correct and acceptable?

Comment: You've got some errors and/or confusing bits in there.  Here is something that you can use as an organizing principle: First, note that $(1\pm \sqrt 5)/2$ are the two roots of $x^2=x+1$, and multiply that polynomial by $x^{n-1}$ to show, e.g., that $\phi^{n+1}=\phi^n+\phi^{n-1}$.

Comment: In your displayed equation $${1\over\phi}=\cdots=-(-{1\over\phi})^n$$ everything is OK except for the very last expression, which doesn't belong there.

Comment: What is the statement you're trying to prove?

Comment: @Shaun The author asked for a proof (by induction) that $$F_n=\frac{\left(\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2\right)^n-\left(\frac {1-\sqrt 5}2\right)^n}{\sqrt 5}$$ is equivalent to $$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$$

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for your edit, I put the exact question #30 form the book to make it clear as to what I'm trying to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your proof seems correct and acceptable (given the edit).